# How to print all rows in Excel workbook using rs.next()?

Tags: java, excel

I am reading an Excel workbook with three columns and many rows and am using rs.next() to print the values of all rows, but it's printing only the first row values.

I tried both the following, but it always prints only the first row, and rowscount =1.

```
Statement s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ltSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY)
Statement s = con.createStatement();
```

Here is my code so far. Can someone tell me how to get all rows to print?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=D:\\Test.xls");
            //Statement s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
      Statement s = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]");        
            int rowcount=0;
            if(rs.next())
            {                    
                String userid1=rs.getString("UserId");
                System.out.println(userid1);
                ++rowcount;
            }
            System.out.println("Total number of records = " + rowcount);
            rs.close();


    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `while` loop instead of `if` statement.

`If` statement will execute only once, but it will not loop to get your desired result.

```
while(rs.next())
{                    
  String userid1=rs.getString("UserId");
  System.out.println(userid1);
  ++rowcount;
}
```

Replace your if block entirely with above code.

Comment: It's working i did a big mistake thanks to all ofYou

Answer (score 0):

```
replace the if(rs.next()) with while(rs.next())
```